# How to count clicks with php/mysql on different links which procedes to the same page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, counter

I'm working on a clickcounter with php and mysql. I have a few different links I want counted, the issue is that all the links send you to the same page. I I've completed the display part like this:

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT c_img FROM cigg ORDER BY c_counter DESC");
$stmt->execute();

echo '</div>';
echo '<h1>Popularity</h1>';
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<a href="index3.php"><img src="images/cigg/' . $row['c_img'] . '"width="150px" height="150px"/></a>';
}

?>
```

This displays 8 different image-clickable links where all will send you to index3.php

My problem is that I want all the clicks on these links to be counted.

What I have so far is a like a half query, barely anything at all and I'm not even sure if it's correct. But I'm really stuck and can't figure it out.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE cigg SET c_counter = c_counter + 1 WHERE ?");
$stmt->execute();
```

And here's is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cigg` (
  `c_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `c_price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c_img` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `c_counter` int(11), 
  PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=33 ;
```

I'm not sure what the right approach is. If it's by using `$_GET` to catch the correct id's in the url, or is there's any other way of doing this? I've searched for hours but still stuck. I only started with php a couple of days ago so I'm not any good, that's why I'm stuck with this. So to sum up my question is, how is my approach if I want to count number of clicks on these links?

Answer (score 0):

You can fire a pixel image with a different get for each link.

Like you add a js .on click or something like that and you can load or create a 1X1 pixel image once the a is clicked.

Other option could be to use jQuery load or to send a post or something like that once the click event is fired for each of the links.

There is plenty of options for that.